# Ruby on Rails returns 404 on existing resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, serialization, activerecord, cancancan

I have a Rails Backend that connects to a Postgres Database. And I have a method that is an index for a resource. Basically:

```
/users/{id}
```

My code is as follows:

```
  def show
    render json: @user, serializer_options: { actions: true, statistics: true }
  end
```

@user is being set using load_and_authorize_resource of CanCan. Like this:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :user, through: :company, shallow: true
```

and this is being set with the ID provided in the URL as params.

And I'm using a serializer. The problem is the show route is returning 404 on a single ID. And it works correctly on every other ID as far as I can tell. Also, the record exists in the database.

I'm sure the user exists because when I run:

```
User.find({id})
```

on the console it returns the User correctly.

So, for some reason Rails is not being able to find this record. Is there any way for me to debug this issue?

Comment: Have you confirmed @user is set? you can add `debugger` before @user assignment and verify user finder code in server console.

Comment: How are you setting `@user`? How are you sure this user exists? What query is being executed? You haven't provided us a lot to go on here so it will be very difficult to assist.

Comment: @engineersmnky, @user is being set using load_and_authorize_resource of CanCan. Like this: `load_and_authorize_resource :user, through: :company, shallow: true`, and this is being set with the ID provided in the URL as params. I'm sure the user exists because when I run User.find({id}) on the console it returns the User correctly.

Comment: You should add this to the post itself so it is not lost in the comments. Also Post the queries that are being executed. These can be found in the log output.

Comment: Before the .find request, try `puts "----> #{User.where(id: id).first}`  to ensure the issue is that the Rails server is seeing the user record, and there isn't some race or transaction issue. If this works, you'll see the record. If you don't even see the  `---->` string then the issue might be your route. Are you using integer IDs? Maybe you could post more controller code, just in case.

Comment: Since you're using the `through: :company` option for the CanCan call, the user is actually being loaded with something like `@company.users.find(params[:id])`. I would double check that the user belongs to the company you expect. If all looks right, set the logs to the DEBUG level and watch what query gets executed when you try to load the page -- it should show the failing query. Note that the 404 is an automatic response in Rails to any ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. Here is how I came to an answer. I ran the following on the console:

```
user = User.find({id})
ApplicationController.render json: user, serializer: UserSerializer
```

This showed me the exact value that was making the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. Turns out there is a location inside my application that is allowing an invalid id to be saved. So the database was not finding the record. It had nothing to do with the user, but it happened in the serializer.